# Add row to HTML <Select> at Run-time in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have an HTML `<Select>` with `runat="server"` in asp.net.

I want to add row to the `<Select>` On click event of a button or some thing like that, my option is like:

```
 <select id="lanHtml" runat="server"> </select>
```

I tried

```
lanHtml.InnerHtml = "<option value='en'>english</option>";
```

but it does not work and I get this exception:

> 'HtmlSelect' does not support the InnerHtml property.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: no , i need **asp.net cs code**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var o = lanHtml as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlSelect;

if(o!=null)
{
    o.Items.Add(new ListItem("English", "En"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
lanHtml.Items.Add(new ListItem("English", "En"));
lanHtml.Items.Add(new ListItem("French", "Fr"));
```